# jquery upload plugin - valums - how to change the user interface

Tags: jquery-plugins

I would like to change the user interface for the jquery ajax upload plugin valums(from the default upload button to some image). Is there a method in it or direct dom updating which is not looking very good.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css and add a background image to the `.qq-upload-button` class:

```
.qq-upload-button, .qq-upload-button:hover {
   background-image:url('your-image.jpg');
   border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   display: block;
   padding: 7px 0;
   text-align: center;
   width: 105px;
   height: 32px;
}
```

You will have to change the `your-image.jpg` to the path and filename of your own image and you will need to set the `width` and `height` properties based on the image dimensions.

Comment: Thanks..I was just thinking about the background image and came to this to see I saw your answer..But for text still you still would have to do some dom manipulation..and in firefox..it doesn't show the mouse over on the top area and bottom are of the button.

Comment: @coool - What text do you want to set? You can use css content to add text.